# PDFBOX Integration with AEM Project

Tags: java, maven, aem

I am not getting the correct answer, I created a separate `pdfbox osgi bundle` and deployed successfully.

It has the `active` status. And the project bundle is also deployed having the `active` status.

but I get the following error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument

Comment: You probably want to show more of the stacktrace. Maybe share the version of pdfbox, too, as it has gone through some changes at major  revisions. It sounds like you don't have a support library on the classpath.

Comment: Check the exports of the `pdfbox osgi bundle`. If the bundle does not export the classes, no other bundle can use them. The result is the `NoClassDefFoundError` you see.

Comment: Looks like pdfbox is published as a bundle here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox/2.0.15 so you don’t need to “create” a bundle.just download the bundle and install it via Felix console for testing. Then you can include that bundle in the install directory or via the maven bundle plugin to deploy everything in one package.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?